# Drawing in NativeScript/Angular application?

Tags: angular, nativescript

Are there any way to draw, say,  lines, boxes, curves (directly or indirectly) in   NativeScript/Angular  application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript/Angular have no methods to create the shapes. You need to use hand-coded JavaScript.

There are also number of [modules](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/drawing) that you can use suitable for your requirement.

I would suggest you to look into [Drawingpad module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-drawingpad) which is built for nativescript.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138752/bhojendra-rauniyar
Do you have any idea to get drawing pad image with background image?